# CSS not working for IE - border style change

Tags: javascript, css

I have a validation code where I want to change the border color to RED of my input text if the input text is blank or onblur.

In FF and Chrome, it works fine. 
In IE10, it doesn't work.

Here's my script

```
function onblur_style() {
var x = document.forms["myform"]["MySearchKeywordInput"].value;
    if (x != "" || x != null) {
        document.getElementById("MySearchBox").style="border: 2px solid #5A5A5A;color: red";
    } 
}

function validateForm() {
var y = document.forms["myform"]["MySearchKeywordInput"].value;
    if (y==null || y=="") {        
        alert("At least one search query is required.");
        document.getElementById("MySearchBox").style="border: 2px solid #FF0000;color: red";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }
}
```

Here's my html

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="http://submitpage.page" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="MySearchBox" name="MySearchKeywordInput" maxlength="60" size="180" value="Search for solutions" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="onblur_style()">
</td>
<td>
<input type="image" src="http://image/magnifying_glass.gif">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me in any browser. 
http://jsfiddle.net/96pqmvLm/

Comment: The name for the input field in the javascript is incorrect according to the name in the html.

Comment: Also `document.forms["myform"]["MySearchKeywordInput"]` You need to use the name of the form, not the id.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the `style` **property** with the `style` **attribute**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you seem to be confusing the `style` **property** with the `style` **attribute**.

If you want to use the property, try something like this...

```
var searchBoxStyle = document.getElementById("MySearchBox").style;
searchBoxStyle.border = '2px solid #5A5A5A';
searchBoxStyle.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 1):

The style property of DOM elements is an object that holds values for different style properties. Thus if you want to change the border and color of an element through the style property then you need to do this:

```
element.style.border = "2px solid #5A5A5A";
element.style.color = "#FF3030";
```

If you want to change the style attribute of the element like in your example you need to do this:

```
element.setAttribute("style", "border: 2px solid #5A5A5A; color: red");
```